# Force gradle build failure on deprecated usage

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1. I'd like to receive a build failure if a deprecated API is used. Currently I change the error level in the settings but the build gives me just a warning. I tried to put in gradle file:

```
lintOptions {
    abortOnError true
}
```

but it doesn't work. Is there any code I can use in the gradle file or any option?

Answer (score 2):

In your root `build.gradle`, try:

```
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.deprecation = true
        options.compilerArgs += ['-Werror']
    }
}
```

Works for me on Android Studio 2.2.