# How to enable lint error in Android Studio for message "Call requires API level 21 (current min is 16)"?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-lint

I have a method called `setImageTintList()` that requires min API to be 21. But, if I set my min API to 16 in gradle, the app still builds without any warning.

Although there is a red line saying:

> setImageTintList() - Call requires API level 21 (current min is 16)

it does not show any warning, error or compile error.

How can I set the lint warning level in android studio such that it will error out and possibly prevent the build in cases like this?

Comment: It will compile, but it will probably crash if older versions of the app (pre 21) hit the method.

Comment: did you check that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631131/how-do-we-configure-android-studio-to-run-its-lint-on-every-build?rq=1

Comment: @zgc7009 Yup. The app crashes on api < 21.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35706305/force-gradle-build-failure-on-deprecated-usage

Comment: Did you find any solutions for this issue? I can't see the message also.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the Android's gradle plugin lint is not able to report invalid Android API calls as errors.

But you can use the **[gradle-animalsniffer-plugin](https://github.com/xvik/gradle-animalsniffer-plugin)** to achieve the same.